# Fatal error: Call to undefined method - error

Tags: php, mysqli

This is how I'm working on that one should only your front text, so that I will not make it through the database:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mebe :: admin_tekst () in / home / jesperbo / public_html / blabla.dk / admin_forside.php on line 30

```
function admin_tekst()
     {
             if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `tekst` FROM `forside_tekst`'))
             { 
                 $stmt->execute();
                 $stmt->store_result();

                 $stmt->bind_result($tekst);

                 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                 ?>
                 <form action="#" method="post">
                     <textarea name="tekst" cols="20" rows="15" class="new" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $tekst;?></textarea>
                     <input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret Blog" class="new">
                 </form>
                 <?php
                 }
                 $stmt->close();

             } else {
                 echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
             }    

     }
```

When I get it it's like this:

```
<?php

                     $admin_tekst = $mebe->admin_tekst();

                     if(isset($_POST["opret"]))
                     {
                         $updater_forside = $mebe->updater_forside();
                     }

                 ?>
```

updater works perfectly fine without any problems right now.

it is admin_tekst() which is the problem

When I get information to the page:

```
session_start();
 require_once("indhold/inc/fun_db.php");
 $mebe = new mebe;
 $db = $mebe->db_c();
```

so here it seems the start of my function file:

```
if(IN_DEBUG_MODE){
     ini_set("display_startup_errors", "on");
     ini_set("display_errors", "on");
       ini_set("html_errors", "false");
     error_reporting(-1); // -1 viser alle slags fejl beskeder
     ini_set("ignore_repeated_errors", 0);
 }
 else{
     error_reporting(0);
 }

 class mebe
 {

 private $mysqli;
     function db_c()
     {
         $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', '..', '..', '..');

         if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
             die('Fejl : ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
         }
         mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
         $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
     }


     function admin_tekst()
     {
             if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `tekst` FROM `forside_tekst`'))
             { 
                 $stmt->execute();
                 $stmt->store_result();

                 $stmt->bind_result($tekst);

                 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                 ?>
                 <form action="#" method="post">
                     <textarea name="tekst" cols="20" rows="15" class="new" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $tekst;?></textarea>
                     <input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret Blog" class="new">
                 </form>
                 <?php
                 }
                 $stmt->close();

             } else {
                 echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
             }    

     }


     }

 }
```

All the other function works fine *example*:

```
function updater_forside()
     {
         if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `forside_tekst` SET `tekst`=? WHERE `id`=?'))
         { 
             $stmt->bind_param('si', $tekst, $id);

             $tekst = $_POST["tekst"]; 
             $id = 1;

             $stmt->execute();

             $stmt->close();

         }
         else
         {
             echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
         }
     }
```

it will also bring in admin_forside.php and works without problems. Will not be any fault at all!.

Comment: You need to explain this better. you jump between code snippets without explaining at all how they relate to each other. Is your code snippet with "When I get it it's like this" the entire script? is it a snippet?

Comment: might follow you. I cuisine straight to where the files / function is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make public your function inside class **mebe** like this:

```
public function admin_tekst()
```

in your code:

```
 class mebe
 {

     private $mysqli;

     function db_c()
     {
     ...
     }


     public function admin_tekst()
     { ...
```

Comment: I have several function of the file is just over 2000 lines of code.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/indhold/inc/fun_db.php on line 2015

`public function forside_select()`

Comment: First Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mebe :: admin_tekst ()

Comment: Second Error: syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in .... on line 2015 public function forside_select()

Comment: my problem was that I had two "}" to last and that was it went and affects the entire